# How to convert tiff image to jpeg using r

Tags: r, image, jpeg, tiff

I have a hundred image that are in TIFF format, I want to convert them to JPEG format. I use the R language. could you please tell me what function or what package should I use to make this conversion in r. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think R is not the right tool for that. My suggestion is have a look e.g. at imagemagick, if you are using Linux you will find further information [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60401/batch-processing-tif-images-converting-tif-to-jpeg)

Comment: You can use R to read file names and pass that to `convert` of ImageMagic (as Daniel suggested).

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, is it possible to do this conversion on Matlab too?

Comment: thank you, ImageMagick can convert one hundred of  images on the same time or per image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An indirect way to convert tiff to jpeg image is to read TIFF image and then write JPEG using package tiff and jpeg. For example:

```
#Load
library("jpeg")
library("tiff")

img <- readTIFF("origin.tiff", native=TRUE)
writeJPEG(img, target = "Converted.jpeg", quality = 1)
```